# Merging data of two SQL Server tables with auto Increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Using SQL Server, I have two tables that I want to merge. Table2 has a `tbID` column that has NULL values. I would like for NULL values to be automatically updated, beginning with the next value of the tbID column, from Table1 when the tables are merged.

I am entering something like this..

```
SELECT 
    A.tbID,
    A.etID,
    A.cNumber,
    A.cName
FROM 
    Table1 AS A

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    B.tbID,
    B.etID,
    B.cNumber,
    B.cName
FROM 
    Table2 AS B
```

My results has a NULL value (instead of an automatically inserted number), in the records from Table2.

Comment: Your query just selects the records from both tables, and of course returns NULL when there is NULL. Do you want to insert the records from Table2 into Table1?

Comment: @WolfgangK Yes I do, but I need for the tbID column to auto increment, beginning with the next value of the tbID column.  For instance, the last row in Table1 has a value of 12, in the tbID column.  I would like for the first row from Table2 to then have a value of 13, in the tbID column, when the tables are merged.

Answer (score 2):

If by "merge" you want all the records to end up in `table1` - just leave the id column out of the insert:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (etID, cNumber, cName)
SELECT etID, cNumber, cName
FROM table2
```

If you just want to select and see incremented ids for the data coming from `table2`, here is one way:

```
SELECT A.tbID,
       A.etID,
       A.cNumber,
       A.cName
FROM Table1 AS A

UNION ALL

SELECT (SELECT MAX(tbID) FROM Table1) + 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.etID),
       B.etID,
       B.cNumber,
       B.cName
FROM Table2 AS B
```

Comment: I will give your second suggestion a try @Aaron.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a result set, you can use:

```
SELECT A.tbID, A.etID, A.cNumber, A.cName
FROM Table1 A
UNION ALL
SELECT (a.maxID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) as tbID,
       B.etID, B.cNumber, B.cName
FROM Table2 B CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(A.tbID) as maxID FROM Table1 as A) a;
```

If you are inserting these rows into a new table, then the id can be assigned automatically -- but the values might differ for `A`.